# Measuring response time for a Vaadin/Atmosphere based application

Tags: performance, logging, websocket, vaadin, atmosphere

I have a Vaadin application that is using web sockets (Atmosphere) to push data to the browser. This means that there is no normal HTTP request/response cycle. From the looks of it, I do get HTTP GET requests, but the response is pushed out via the web socket asynchronously.

Because of this the response time (and message size) metrics I can get from the web server logs are useless.

How can I get information logged as to how long every request processing took?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Developer Tools allows you to see time stamps of messages sent using web sockets (in the Network tab).